# Por que é que no sotaque de Portugal o "o" átono inicial é aberto?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia, fonologia

Em Portugal o *o* átono é normalmente pronunciado /u/, não só no fim de palavra como acontece também no Brasil e em África, mas também noutras posições. Por exemplo *poroso* é pronunciado /pu’ɾozu/, e *fonológico* é /funu’lɔʒiku/. No entanto isto parece nunca acontecer quando o *o* é a primeira letra da palavra, onde o *o* é aberto mesmo quando átono. Comparemos (links à Infopédia com transcrição fonética e ao Forvo com reprodução audio):

> *(o) [c**o**ração](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o)* e [***o***ração](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o)—[/k**u**ɾɐ’sɐ̃w/](https://pt.forvo.com/word/cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt) mas [/**ɔ**ɾɐ’sɐ̃w/](https://pt.forvo.com/word/ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt)
>
> [*provação*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/prova%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [*ovação*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ova%C3%A7%C3%A3o)—/pɾ**u**vɐ’sɐ̃w/ mas /**ɔ**vɐ’sɐ̃w/
>
> [*c**o**brar*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/cobrar) e [***o***brar](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/obrar)—[/k**u**’bɾaɾ/] mas /**ɔ**’bɾaɾ/
>
> [*r**o**deio*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/rodeio) e ***o***deio—/ɾ**u**’dɐju/ mas /**ɔ**’dɐju/ ou  /**o**’dɐju/

Já agora, para tentar ser completo, creio que no Brasil os *oo* assinalados são sempre fechados (/o/); enquanto em África, segundo o modelo experimental do [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=14614) é /o/ como no Brasil quando antecedido de consoante, (*coração*, etc.), mas tende a ser aberto como em Portugal quando começa a palavra.

Já no exemplo seguinte, com duas palavras com a mesma raiz, parece que um fenómeno semelhante acontece também no Brasil, o que provavelmente tem que ver só com a pronúncia de dois *oo* seguidos:

> [*cooperação*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/coopera%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [*operação*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o)— [*B* /kw**u**peɾɐ’sɐ̃w/, *P* /kw**u**pɨɾɐ’sɐ̃w/](https://pt.forvo.com/word/coopera%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt) mas [*B* /**o**peɾɐ’sɐ̃w/](https://pt.forvo.com/word/opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt), *P* /**ɔ**pɨɾɐ’sɐ̃w/

Isto em Portugal será assim só porque é, um mero acidente na evolução da língua, ou há alguma explicação fonológica para o *o* em início da palavra resistir à redução em /u/ que acontece quando antecedido de consoante?

Comment: Nos primeiros exemplos, eu pronuncio todos os "oo" da mesma forma.  No segundo exemplo (cooperação e operação) também pronuncio os dois da mesma forma. Por vezes acho que eu pronuncio os dois "o", da mesma forma que pronuncio os "ee" em compreender.

Comment: Eu escutei alguns brasileiros no forvo: uns dizem /wu/ [cooperação](https://pt.forvo.com/word/coopera%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt) e [cooperativa](https://forvo.com/word/cooperativa/#pt); outro diz /oo/ em [coordenação](https://pt.forvo.com/word/coordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt). É capaz de coexistirem pronúncias diferentes?

Comment: Com certeza....

Comment: @Jacinto Sim. Um brasileiro com esta pronúncia seria prejulgado como alguém com baixo nível de educação formal, ao menos na minha região. Mas, ainda assim, ela existe, e é comum.

Comment: @Centaurus Também pronuncio da mesma forma, mas creio que haja um pouco de viés de confirmação em nossa avaliação. Eu certamente pronuncio _oo_ e _ee_, em hiatos, quando preciso dar ênfase ou falar devagar. Mas, no cotidiano, vogais repetidas estão fadadas a serem condensadas, ou ainda pior, transformadas em ditongos. Um amigo escocês frequentemente me provocava por usar a mesma pronúncia para "voo", "Vol" e "vou".

Comment: @RamonMelo   O pior é que eu normalmente nem sei como pronuncio as palavras.  Só falando para saber, e só faço isso quando alguém faz alguma observação, quando ouço pronuncias bem diferentes ou quando entro aqui no site.  Eu acho que pronuncio "Eu voo para Paris amanhã" e "Eu vou para Paris amanhã" de formas diferentes.  Informalmente eu tendo a pronunciar "Eu 'vô' (vou) pra Paris"

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, foi o que eu quis expressar com "viés de confirmação". Na busca por encontrar as diferenças, a pronúncia que sai das nossas bocas acaba sendo distinta da nossa pronúncia "normal". Eu costumo usar um gravador de voz e repetir a mesma palavra várias vezes seguidas até encontrar uma pronúncia que me soe familiar.

Comment: Acho que pronuncio voo separado como 'vo-u' ou 'vol-u', E vou como única sílaba 'vol'. (pt-BR)

Comment: @AndréLyra Eu também pronuncio assim: *vou* é como *vô*; e *voo* é 'vo-u'.

Comment: @Jacinto Em Portugal o canónico é ler coração, provação, cobrar, rodeio, odeio e cooperação na forma /o/ se bem que há regiões em algumas destas palavras (mas não todas) se lêem como indicou.

Comment: @Jonas /o/ como em *t**o**do?* Eu nunca ouvi nenhum português pronunciar /ko'bɾaɾ/. O [dicionário da Porto Editora](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/cobrar) indica /ku'bɾaɾ/; o [Portal da língua portguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=55038) também (só para Lisboa); e o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa também. E o mesmo para todas as palavras na minha lista.

Comment: @Jacinto Bom, nunca ouvi ninguém dizer como dizem os dicionários. Com umas décadas em cima deste seu amigo, e bastantes livros escritos, não vou olhar para lá. :) Sim, é de facto como em t**o**do.

Comment: O som do *o* inicial é aberto sempre, ou só quando o *o* sozinho forma a primeira sílaba? Acontece a mesma coisa com o *e* inicial?

Comment: O som de *or* e *os* iniciais tendem também a ser abertos (*orçamento, osteologia*), mas aqui já há alguma oscilação, com algumas palavras pronunciadas com *o* aberto por umas pessoas e fechado por outras. O *e* átono inicial passa em Portugal normalmente a [ i ] como em *educar, efémero, elegante, emigrar, etéreo*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para começar, é bem estudado o fenômeno pelo qual as [consoantes soantes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consoante_soante) na coda silábica impedem a redução da vogal precedente em casos nos quais deveria acontecer; isto é, não acontece redução (de /o/ para [u], de /e/ para [ɨ]) quando a vogal não acentuada é seguida por nasal, /l/, /r/ ou semivogal.

Um *paper* ([A Estrutura da Sílaba em Português Europeu](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0102-44501998000100002)) apresenta a hipótese de que a sílaba normal em português deve ter sempre um ataque (*onset*), isto é, começar em consoante. As vogais iniciais são anômalas e portanto o processo de redução não acontece nesses casos, mesmo que não sejam seguidas por uma sonorante.

O livro *[The Prosodic Word in European Portuguese](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=epnbYAYW4t8C)* comenta e rejeita essa hipótese. Estudando as vogais iniciais em português européu a autora demostra que a redução é sempre menor nelas (ainda que existam variações entre falantes e entre dialetos) e atribui isso a um "fortalecimento da posição inicial, que pode ser visto como uma propriedade da prosódia". Traduzindo:

> Por contraste, a hipótese de que a redução das vogais não é tão extrema inicialmente quanto no interior da palavra porque esta posição é prosódicamente forte (…) é consistente com outros fenômenos fonológicos que caraterizam esta posição e que podem ser relacionados com sua força: por example, fortalecimento do /ɾ/, acentuação inicial e asignação do acento enfático (…). Além disso tem pelo menos outro caso no qual as vogais não acentuadas em uma posição específica da palavra prosódica não ficam sujeitas a redução: quando as vogais ocorrem em sílabas fechadas por uma consoante sonorante na *posição de fim de palavra prosódica*.

O livro tem também alguns exemplos onde uma vogal não acentuada, em uma sílaba aberta e sem ataque, mas não inicial, é reduzida normalmente, o qual discorda com a primeira hipótese.

Porém acho que existem algumas diferenças entre o que os dois estudos consideram redução e onde encontram que a redução é bloqueada pelas sonorantes. Segundo o primeiro, aparentemente, pronunciar o *e* inicial de *elefante* como [i] não é redução (ou não é uma redução completa), ja que nessa posição o som /e/ deveria se reduzir a [ɨ]. (As fontes que eu consultei dizem que as vogais não acentuadas em pt-pt sempre reduzem-se a [ɨ], [u] ou [ɐ].)

Comment: É possível que exista com o *e* inicial um fenómeno paralelo ao do *o*. Por exemplo,o primeiro *e* é [ɨ] em *relevar*, mas [i] em *elevar*. Por *sonorante* quererás dizer *sonora* (*voiced* em inglês)?

Comment: Em Portugal existe redução do *o* átono para [u] e *e* átono para [ɨ] mesmo se a sílaba terminar em *r*, como em *cortar, porcaria, permanente, acertar*. Creio que isto é o padrão e não a exceção. Isto não acontece é na última sílaba , mas há poucas palavras com esse padrão (*caráter, cárter*).

Comment: @Jacinto Não, por sonorante eu quero dizer [soante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consoante_soante). (Achei que "sonorante" era correto em pt mas parece que a palavra aceitada é "soante".) Básicamente são as líquidas, nasais e semivogais.